# Bootstrap method & Confidence Interval

Tags: statistics, confidence-interval, quantile, bootstrap-sampling

I'm trying to figure out how this method works.
My data:

- 1000 samples from unknown distribution.
- I need to create 40 vectors from those 1000 samples (each vector with 20 samples)
- For every one of the 40 vectors, I need to do the bootstrap method for:

  - Finding the confidence interval ($\alpha$ = 0.05) in three methods: t, quantiles & normal.
  - We need the confidence interval for the standard deviation.

(R langauge)

My way until now:

- I've created this 40 vectors (each one with 20 samples)
- Let's say that the bootstrap constant is 1000.
- What is actually the process of "doing bootstrap" for each vector with 20 samples? How can we create a confidence interval for this vector in each one of these methods I've mentioned?

I will be glad for any help.

Comment: Your post has been edited and re-structured. I checked against the original and the edit seems OK. But your question is long, and I would urge you to verify if the 'bullet' structure of the edit is what you intended. // Are you interested _only_ in confidence intervals for the population standard deviation $\sigma?$ What you mean by the 3 methods (t, quantiles, normal) is not exactly clear; bootstrapping is only a few decades old and the terminology is still not totally standard. Can you provide R code for at least one of the methods?

Comment: Please edit the information in your 'Comment as Answer' into your Question. Do you mean _standard deviation_ ('Standardabweichung') instead of _standard mean_? Or do you mean _standard error of the mean_? At the very least, _in your title_, you should be able to say what you are estimating--mean ($\mu$), SD ($\sigma$), SE ($\sigma/\sqrt{n}$). (Then delete your non-Answer, before it attracts down-votes.) My answer uses a quantile method. I don't see how a method with t or normal would work for SD. Maybe my code will give you a start.

Answer (score 0):

@BruceET

I cannot comment because i've needed to reset my account.
Anyway, I'm interested only in CI for the population standard mean. By 3 methods, I've meant that there are 3 options to calculate the CI (one with quantiles, one with t distribution, and one with normal distribution).

I wanna provide R code, but that's my challange to understand what is the code :)

Comment: yes, standard deviation.

Comment: Then my Answer is relevant. Does it seem similar to any types of bootstrap procedures you have encountered? In particular, does it match quantile, t, or normal? // BTW, if you want someone to see a comment (quickly), you have to put it at the end of their Answer (or Question) or you have to use `@name` so it will show up on their home page. [You should see this because it's at the end of your Answer.]

Answer (score 0):

Here is one example of finding a 95% nonparametric bootstrap confidence interval for the population standard deviation (SD) $\sigma,$ based on a sample `x` of size $n = 20$ from an unknown population distribution.

```
 x
 [1] 240 314 354 183 321 325 271 273 272 255
[11] 276 250 261 303 348 294 274 254 258 421
s.obs = sd(x);  s.obs
50.67365
```

If we knew the population distribution, we could find the distribution
of the ratio $R = S/\sigma$ based on the population distribution. Then
we could find values $L$ and $U$ that cut 2.5% from the lower tails,
respectively, of the distribution of $R$ so that

$$0.95 = P(L \le R \le U) = P\left(\frac{S}{U} \le \sigma \le \frac{S}{L}\right),$$

where $S$ is the sample SD of the sample of $n = 20.$ Then the desired
95% CI would be  $(S/U,\,S/L).$

However, we do not know the distribution of $R$ and we seek to estimate
$L$ and $U$ by using a bootstrap method.

Enering the so-called *bootstrap world,* we take $B = 1000$ re-samples from `x`, each of them a re-sample of size
$n = 20$ taken *with* replacement from `x`. Temporarily, we take the observed
SD ($S_{obs} =  50.67365$) as a proxy for the unknown population SD $\sigma;$
that is $\sigma^* =  50.67365.$ Then, for each of the $B$ re-samples,
we find $R^* = S^*/\sigma^*.$ We find quantiles .025 and .975 of the
$B$ values $R^*$ as estimates $L^*$ of $L$ and $U^*$ of $U,$ respectively.
[Notice that quantities referring to re-sampling are denoted by $*$'s.

Back in the *real world,* we find the 95% nonparametric bootstrap CI of $\sigma$
as $(S_{obs}/U^*, S_{obs}/L^*).$ [Here $S_{obs}$ returns to its original
role as the observed SD of our sample `x`.]

The R code for this procedure follows. In the code we use `-re` instead of $*$.

```
B = 1000;  n = length(x);  sg.re = s.obs;  r.re = numeric(B)
for (i in 1:B) {
   x.re = sample(x, n, repl=T);  s.re = sd(x.re)
   r.re[i] = s.re/sg.re  }
L.re = quantile(r.re, .025);  U.re = quantile(r.re, .975)
LCL = s.obs/U.re;  UCL = s.obs/L.re
c(LCL, UCL)
   97.5%     2.5% 
37.33546 88.26224
```

So the 95% nonparametric bootstrap CI for $\sigma$ is $(37.3,\,88.3).$
Because this is a simulation procedure, subsequent runs may give
slightly different results. My second run of the program above gave
slightly different results that still round to $(37.3,\,88.3).$

---

Now it is time for a confession: I generated `x` from a normal distribution
as follows:

```
set.seed(1234); x = round(rnorm(20, 300, 50))
```

So I know that the data are normal. The standard 95% CI for $\sigma$ of
a normal population is $\left(\sqrt{\frac{(n-1)S^2}{U_q}}, \sqrt{\frac{(n-1)S^2}{L_q}}\right),$ where $L_q$ and $R_q$ are quantiles .025 and .975, respectively, of
$\mathsf{Chisq}(\nu = n-1).$ So the traditional parametric 95% CI for $\sigma$
is $(38.5, 70.0)$. Because knowing the population distribution introduces
new and useful information into the process of estimation, we cannot expect
the normal-based CI to be the same as the bootstrap CI, but they are not
much different for practical purposes.

```
sqrt((n-1)*var(x) / qchisq(c(.975,.025), n-1))
[1] 38.53682 74.01249
```